# Check if a boolean is true from another java class

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean

How can I check whether a boolean is true or false from another java class?

menu.class

```
public class menu extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView textPoints;
    Button button2;
    public boolean easy;

    public void Click(View v) {
    if (button2.getText().equals("Svårighetsgrad: Svårt")) {
                easy = true;
                button2.setText("Svårighetsgrad: Lätt");
                }
            else {
                easy = false;
                button2.setText("Svårighetsgrad: Svårt");
```

GameActivity.class

```
menu m = new menu();
            if (m.easy == true) {
                myImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                newAndroid();
                points = getPoints() - 1;
                text1.setText("Poäng: " + points);
            }
            else {
                myImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                newAndroid();
                points = getPoints() - 5;
                text1.setText("Poäng: " + points);
```

Comment: Well, since the code is pretty incomplete, there's not much we can help here. From this portion of code, all I can say is: "looks fine to me". Since it apparently doesn't work, a error-message and the full code would be quite helpful. Most likely it's about access-privileges, but can't say that for sure without code

Comment: Is "easy" a field variable?

Comment: make boolean easy acess level public or protected  or default rahter than private.  so it can be accessed out side the class.

Comment: public boolean easy; it's public but it still doesn't work for some reason. It removes 5 points (as shown in gameactivity.class) no matter what.

Answer (score 3):

you are developing for Android right?
you should probably use SharedPreference in this case (it would be easier).

use this code to save value:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putBoolean("EASY", easy);
editor.commit();
```

and this code to get the value:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean score = sharedPref.getBoolean("EASY", defaultValue);
```

Comment: Yes I am developing for android. However, i'd like to solve this problem before I start using more advanced code.

Comment: Thus isn't really advanced. All it does is save your variable on the device. This way you can access it's value even if you closed your app, and then reopened it.

Answer (score 3):

If you're just trying to get whether or not a value is true or false, you could either make your boolean `public` or you could make a getter method.

```
public boolean getBooleanValue(){
    return booleanYouWant;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a reference on that class in order to do that. The common way of communicating would be the [observer pattern](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/observer_pattern.htm) for java. [Delegation](http://best-practice-software-engineering.ifs.tuwien.ac.at/patterns/delegation.html) is also a possibility - which will create a double reference, but in Java you usually want to take observer pattern, as it is implemented by default.

You can also have some kind of [singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), to have a global reference of an instance.